# Kovan Testnet AAVE Flashloan with Brownie Python

Tags: python, brownie, kovan

I am quite new to coding with limited experience, after following the Patrick Collins tutorial on flash loans from AAVE, everything works fine and have the environment installed.

I receive this error upon deploying:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum



File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://kovan.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'   
PS C:\Users\Ash> brownie run scripts/run_flash_loan_v2.py --network kovan
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()    
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars 
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
rownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File ".\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://kovan.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
PS C:\Users\Ash> brownie --version
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum
```

Comment: **(1)** Is this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw7yvGFtOvI&ab_channel=PatrickCollins) what you mean? If yes try to include such information. Nobody knows what tutorial you followed to get that problem. **(2)** Also I'm guessing this is on Windows (not Linux or such)?...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, yes that is correct this is the tutorial I followed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw7yvGFtOvI). I am using Windows 11

Comment: to add to the above, the error occurs when I run the get WETH command: brownie run scripts/get_weth.py --network kovan

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.